# How to configure c.vim so it can compile in Powershell Vim?

Tags: c, powershell, vim, plugins

I don't have this problem when compiling c files in vim on Ubuntu with c.vim plugin, but on Windows I get this error when compiling in vim (from typing \rc or \rr):

```
File C:\Users\Kosine\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
At line:1 char:2
+ . <<<< 'C:\Users\Kosine\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'
    + CategoryInfo         : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException

The term 'gcc.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char: 8
+ gcc.exe <<<<   -Wall -g -00 -c C:/Users/Kosine/Programming/prog0402.c -o C:/User/Kosine/Programming/prog0402.obj > C:/User/Kosine/AppData/Local/Temp/VIeCE08.tmp
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gcc.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorID : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have MinGW already installed and can run gcc outside of vim.  Also, I used `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` and other ps1 files are working too.  Is there a way I can fix this problem so that I could be able to compile inside vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 file was downloaded and has the Internet_Zone flag set.  Use the `Unblock-File` command on this file to unblock it and try again.

Also it could be that VIM is firing up a 32-bit shell. The execution to specific to each PowerShell console - x64 and x86.

Comment: Unblock-File is not recognized cmdlet in my powershell.  Also, Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1  is the profile file that contains custom fuctions that I wrote myself.

I noticed that when vim tries to compile the c file, it could be using a different Powershell session (since that error message does not appear on the Powershell after I close vim).  I had to print screen the error message before it disappears for about a second.  I hope I am making sense.

Comment: I added a line in .vimrc file that fixed the first error:

`set shell=powershell.exe\ -ExecutionPolicy\ Unrestricted`  

But it still could not find gcc.exe.

Comment: That will do it as well.  It could be that VIM is firing up a 32-bit shell.  The execution to specific to each PowerShell console - x64 and x86.